# Using material-ui's useMediaQuery in Next.js causes style flickering on first rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, media-queries

Using `@mui/material/useMediaQuery` in `Next.js` causes style flickering on first rendering.

I know this is due to the `useMediaQuery` value changing between server side and client side.
Is there any way to fix this?

```js
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
...
const theme = useTheme();
const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));
...
<Typography variant={matches ? 'subtitle1' : 'h5'}>
  {text}
</Typography>
```

Although this can be easily resolved by specifying display as shown below to switch the `display`
This verbose writing style should be avoided as much as possible.

```js
<Typography sx={{ display: {xs: 'block', md: 'none'} }} variant={'subtitle1'}>
  {text}
</Typography>

<Typography sx={{ display: {xs: 'none', md: 'block'} }} variant={'h5'}>
  {text}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible because the `useMediaQuery` hook uses JavaScript and the server side does not know the viewport size so it's not able to guess the value of `matches` and render it properly.

The only way to avoid this flicker and make the server-rendered version to be displayed correctly is using only CSS, not JavaScript. Unfortunately, you have to stick to the solution you presented in your second code example.

The best you can do is make this CSS solution a bit more readable. For example, I like naming my media queries and using them like here:

```
const mobileQuery = theme.breakpoints.down('md');
const desktopQuery = theme.breakpoints.up('md');

return (
  <>
    <Typography
      sx={{ [desktopQuery]: { display: 'none' } }}
      variant={'subtitle1'}
    >
      {text}
    </Typography>
  
    <Typography
      sx={{ [mobileQuery]: { display: 'none' } }}
      variant={'h5'}
    >
      {text}
    </Typography>
  </>
)
```

Comment: `dry` do not repeat yourself. You can reduce this code down.

Comment: any example? I don't see a good way to avoid repetition in this case